# passing pointer as argument in function (named: insertattail) still its not assignning the value

Tags: c++

the question is isnt head is a pointer whois pointing to null at first.so im passing the head pointer still the output is blank but when i put & before head in function (named: insertattail)
argument then it runs properly so &head isnt mean address of pointer head . help me to remove
confusion in this program

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node{
    public:
    int data;
    struct node* next;

    node(int x)
    {
        data=x;
        next=NULL;
    }
 };

void insertattail(node* head,int val)
{
    node* p=new node(val); 
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=p;
    return;
    }

    node* temp;
    temp=head;

    while (temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    temp->next=p;
    return;
    

}

int main()
{
    node* head=NULL;

    insertattail(head,34);
    insertattail(head,44);
    
    show(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `head` function argument is not the same pointer parameter you passed to the function - it's a copy. You need to use rather a pointer to pointer, i.e. `insertattail(node **head, int val)` and call it like `insertattail(&head, 34)` in main().

Comment: You pass the pointer *by value*, which means the function receives a *copy* of the pointer. To modify any value (including a pointer) inside a function you need to pass *by reference*.

Comment: As an alternative, *return* the `head`.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are passed by value and only if you ask for it they are passed by reference:

```
#include <cassert>

void foo_value(int y) { ++y; }
void foo_ref(int& y) { ++y; }

int main() {
    int x = 0;    
    int old_value = x;

    foo_value(x);
    assert(x == old_value);     // x did not get modified !

    foo_ref(x);
    assert(x != old_value);     // x did get modified !
}
```

Pointers are no exception:
#include

```
void bar_value(int* x) { x = nullptr; }
void bar_ref(int*& x) { x = nullptr; }

int main() { 
    int x = 0;
    int* p = &x;
    int* old_value = p;
    
    bar_value(p);
    assert(p == old_value);    // p did not get modified !

    bar_ref(p);
    assert(p != old_value);    // p did get modified !
}
```

Comment: first code where u write &y  it causes an error looks like   >jj.c:6:17: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
 void foo_ref(int& y)
                 ^
jj.c: In function 'main':
jj.c:13:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'foo_ref' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 foo_ref(x);
 ^~~~~~~

Comment: @ROCKY007 what do you mean? code examples are only for illustration, of course the calls cannot be on file scope. No errors here: https://godbolt.org/z/v1o19ocds

Comment: @ROCKY007 and the function definitions cannot be inside `main`, not sure what caused your eror, but I guess it is that

Comment: how can u store int value to another int address same thing happens AS in pointer case 2

Comment: @ROCKY007 I dont understand the question. See edit, hope it is more clear